# How to generate cobertura report using sbt scoverage

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, cobertura, scoverage

I've a scala app where I use sbt scoverage plugin to generate coverage report.
Now the problem is that I use Jenkins for CI and the generated HTML scoverage report cannot be visualized and this is a [known issue](https://github.com/shanbin/scoverage-plugin/issues/15).

Alternatively, how I can generate cobertura compatible report?? (as I'm able to visualize them in Jenkins for a JS app)

Comment: i know this is old but for me, using sbt-scoverage 2.0.3, the cobertura report is generated automatically.

Comment: this problem is related to visualizing the report on jenkins but yes locally it works fine